# sigma field generated by two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How do I show that the sigma field generated by two random variables, $(X,Y)$, same as sigma field generated by $(X+Y, Y)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244117/sigma-field-generated-by-a-random-variable), the sigma field generated by $X$ and $Y$ is the minimal sigma field containing sets of the form $\{X<x\},\ \{Y<y\}$.

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ be some arbitrary numbers. Sets $\{X<x\}$ and $\{Y<y\}$ are contained in the sigma algebra generated by $(X+Y, Y)$ as we can write $\{X<x\}=\{X+Y < x+y\}\cap\{Y=y\}$ ($\{Y=y\}$ can also be written as a countable intersection of sets from $\sigma(Y)$).

Similarly, for arbitrary $z,y\in \mathbb{R}$, we can write $\{X+Y < z\}=\{X<z-y\}\cap\{Y=y \}$. Thus, every set in $\sigma(X+Y, Y)$ is also contained in $\sigma(X,Y)$.

Therefore, those sigma fields are equal as each one is a subset of the other.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, Blaza.